# Установка иконки для QT С++ приложения на MacOS

Tags: c++, qt, macos

Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке установки иконки для своего MacOS QT приложения. Следовал туториалу, поместил файл формата .icns в папку проекта. в .pro файле прописал:

`ICON = "/Users/philipp/Desktop/Electro/logo.icns"`

Пробовал с кавычками и без, полный путь к файлу и просто имя файла. Собирал на релиз. Но всё ещё вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой?

Comment: В первой же ссылке из поиска (здесь: https://m.habr.com/ru/company/istodo/blog/215079/) написано по другому - добавить в .pro `macx:ICON = $${PWD}/myapp.icns`

Comment: @Стас Спасибо! Помогло!